# Classification of double coverings and $H^1(X ; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

It is a well known fact (see for example Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", chapter $1$) that there is a bijection between the $n$-sheeted coverings of $X$ up to isomorphism of covering spaces and the conjugacy classes of homomorphisms between $\pi_1(X)$ and $S_n$ (where $S_n$ is the symmetric group), under the very poor assumption that $X$ admits universal covering. The proof of this fact (at least, the one presented in Hatcher's book) is quite technical,  although not transcendental.

If we focus our attention on double coverings, things simplify quite a lot, and we have a bijection between the double coverings of $X$ and $Hom(\pi_1(X), S_2)$; by universal coefficient theorem, we have so a bijection
$$\{Double\ coverings\ of\ X\} \longleftrightarrow H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}).$$
Does exist a simpler way to prove this (natural) bijection in this particular case?

Comment: I really like this group, since it has a lot of appearances. 1) Double coverings are in bijection with real line bundles up to isomorphism, by considering the unit sphere. 2) Real line bundles are classified by maps to $\Bbb{RP}^\infty$, and the map to $H^1(X;\Bbb Z/2)$ is given by pulling back the canonical class in $H^1(\Bbb{RP}^\infty; \Bbb Z/2)$. 3) Or, you can determine that class by thinking of the homomorphism that takes a loop to $1$ if it reverses orientation as you walk around that loop. And all of this leaves unsaid the explicit relation to $H_{n-1}(X)$ when $X$ is a manifold!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the universal coefficient theorem and the fact that $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty$ is a $K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},1)$,
$$H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\cong \hom(H_1(X),\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\cong\hom(\pi_1(X),\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\cong[X,\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty],$$
where the square brackets mean homotopy classes of maps $X\to \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty$.

The space $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty$ has a two-fold cover that comes from the unit vectors in the so-called tautological line bundle: each point of projective space is a 1-D subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, so you can make a line bundle where the fiber over each point is the point as a vector space.  In particular, the quotient map $q:S^\infty\to \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty$ is a two-fold cover.

Given a map $f:X\to \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty$, you can pull back this two-fold cover to get one of $X$.$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
f^*(S^\infty) @>>> S^\infty \\
@VpVV @VVqV \\
X @>>f> \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty
\end{CD}
This is independent of the choice of $f$ in its homotopy class.  Naturality is that maps $X\to Y$ give a contravariant map on covering spaces by pullback.

For the converse, we need additional assumptions on our spaces (or so I think: I don't have any counterexamples off the top of my head).  Let $p:X'\to X$ be a two-fold cover.

- If $X$ is paracompact (for example a manifold or a CW complex), then $p$ is the pullback of of $q$ for some map $X\to \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^1$.  (See Milnor-Stasheff, Theorem 5.6.  Promote the cover $p$ to a real line bundle $P:E\to X$ with $p^{-1}(x)$ being the two unit vectors in the fiber.)  This map then yields a first cohomology class by the above isomorphisms.
- If $X$ has a universal cover, then by the classification of covering spaces we know that each two-fold cover is in correspondence with a homomorphism $\pi_1(X)\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

---

If $X$ is a compact $n$-manifold, possibly with boundary, then by Poincare duality $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is $H_{n-1}(X,\partial X;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.  At least when $n\leq 3$, such a homology class can be represented by a properly embedded codimension-1 hypersurface.  The two-fold cover comes from slicing the manifold along these hypersurfaces, then taking two copies of this and gluing them together along the newly exposed boundary.  If a loop in $X$ is orientation-reversing, then the loop must intersect the hypersurface an odd number of times, and a lift of the loop goes from one of the two copies to the other.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. I think you can remove the $n\le3$ restriction, since you have shown the homology class is dual to a cohomology class that comes from a real line bundle, and the zero set of a generic section of that bundle should be a submanifold representative.